# Removing duplicates in list results with unneeded tail

Tags: lambda, prolog

I want to remove all duplicates from a given list .

Consider the following code :

```
% check if the given element is in the given list 
member(Element,[Element|_]).
member(Element,[_|List]):-member(Element, List).


% append the element only if it's NOT already in the input list 
appending([],X,X).
appending([H|T1],Elem,[H|T2]):- appending(T1,Elem,T2).

appendHlp(ListOrg,Res,Addme):- not(member(Addme,ListOrg)),
                   appending(ListOrg,[Addme],Res).
appendHlp(ListOrg,Res,Addme):- member(Addme,ListOrg),
                   Res=ListOrg.

% remove duplicates 
setify([H|T],Set):-appendHlp(Set,Output,H),
           setify(T,Output).
setify([],_).
```

And when I run the code :

```
1 ?- setify([1,2,3,3,2],X).
```

The output is :

```
X = [1, 2, 3|_G2725]
```

How can I remove the tail ?

Thanks

Comment: From a quick look it must be a base case, like setify([],_) instead of setify([],[]).

Comment: @NotAUser: No ,it's not that . When I changed it to `setify([],[])` , it caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite new to Prolog. This is a solution that I came up with to remove duplicate elements. Hope this helps.

```
% Define negation of "member"
notmember(X,L) :- not( member(X,L) ).

% Remove duplicates terminal case
removeDups( [], R, R).

% Case where the head element is a member of tail. Drop it.
removeDups( [H|T], R, A ) :- member(H,T) , removeDups( T, R, A ).

% Case where head element is unique
removeDups([H|T], R, A ) :- notmember(H,T), append(A,[H],N), removeDups(T,R,N).

% Main predicate to remove duplicates with original order maintained.
uniq(X,Y) :- removeDups(X,Y,[]).
```

Comment: This can be coded more efficiently. And what Prolog come with notmember ?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem (superficially) is that member/2 get called with an uninstantiated variable, and then 'builds' the partial list that you see in the output

```
[trace]  ?- setify([1],X).
   Call: (6) setify([1], _G340) ? creep
   Call: (7) appendHlp(_G340, _G416, 1) ? creep
^  Call: (8) not(member(1, _G340)) ? creep
^  Fail: (8) not(user:member(1, _G340)) ? creep
   Redo: (7) appendHlp(_G340, _G416, 1) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:member(1, _G340) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:member(1, [1|_G409]) ? creep
   Call: (8) _G418=[1|_G409] ? creep
   Exit: (8) [1|_G409]=[1|_G409] ? creep
   Exit: (7) appendHlp([1|_G409], [1|_G409], 1) ? creep
   Call: (7) setify([], [1|_G409]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) setify([], [1|_G409]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) setify([1], [1|_G409]) ? creep
X = [1|_G409] .
```

It's not easy to correct, because you use a **very** convoluted way to do a **very** simple task. If you replace, for instance, member with memberchk, or `member(Addme,ListOrg)` with `[Addme]=ListOrg`, your program will fail.

I would advise to take some programming habit accepted by Prolog community. For instance, attempt to place *input* parameters *before* output. It's not always possible, because Prolog is *relational*, but will help to write better code.

Of course, sort/2 would produce the output efficiently and without hassle.

*edit* the solution can be quite compact, in basic Prolog:

```
setify([E|R], U) :- memberchk(E, R), !, setify(R, U).
setify([E|R], [E|U]) :- setify(R, U).
setify([], []).

3 ?- setify([1,1,1,2,1,1],L).
L = [2, 1].
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use SWI-Prolog you can write

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

setify(L, Set) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(memberchk(X, Y)->Z=Y; append(Y, [X], Z)), L, [], Set).
```

Comment: ERROR: source_sink `library(lambda)' does not exist

Comment: lambda.pl can be found at: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl, put it in pl/library.

Answer (score 2):

As CapelliC said, you can just use `sort/2` - it will remove duplicates and sort the elements. And sets are usually represented in sorted form.

If you need to retain original order of the elements, here is not very efficient but very straightforward implementation:

```
setify([H|T], OldSet, NewSet) :-
    ( \+ memberchk(H, OldSet) ->
        append(OldSet, [H], CurrentSet),
        setify(T, CurrentSet, NewSet)
    ;
        setify(T, OldSet, NewSet)
    ).
setify([], OldSet, OldSet).

setify(List, Set) :-
    setify(List, [], Set).
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that uses tail recursion and a single predicate to do the whole thing, but does not preserve the original order.

```
% Finish recursing / empty list
remdup([], []).

% Recurse tail first, don't add H to the list if already included
remdup([H|T], NoDups) :-
    remdup(T, NoDups),
    member(H, NoDups).

% Second rule failed, so H must be unique - add to NoDups list
remdup([H|T], [H|NoDups]) :-
    remdup(T, NoDups).


?- remdup([1,2,2,3,2,1,3,3,3,2],X).
X = [1, 3, 2] .
```